# В чём разница между CFDictionary и CFMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, corefoundation

Здравствуйте, участники форума. Мой вопрос отражён в заголовке. Можно ли выполнить какое-либо приведение типа, чтобы свести CFMutableDictionary к CFDictionary. Заранее спасибо за помощь!)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем приведение, но может `CFDictionaryCreateCopy` подойдет :

```
@function CFDictionaryCreateCopy
Creates a new immutable dictionary with the key-value pairs from the given dictionary.
```

Пример:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    ...    
CFDictionaryRef copy = CFDictionaryCreateCopy(NULL, dict);
CFRelease(dict);
```

Answer (score 1):

Разглядывание http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFDictionary.h показало, что все эти `...ref` типы, по сути, void *.

Может, попробовать через такие приведения типа (только позволит ли компилятор?).

(Правда, стоит отметить, что mutable реально отличается по крайней мере флагами в дескрипторе хэш-таблицы, так что гарантировать работоспособность, не изучая тщательно код, не получится.)

Comment: @avp,
**ref** - означает, что данный тип - ссылочный;    
**CFDictionaryRef** - тип, содержащий пару ключ-значение;    
**CFMutableDictionaryRef** - что это за тип плохо себе представляю...    
**CFTypeRef** - тип (const void *), вроде как к этому типу можно многие другие кастовать.

Comment: @Kristya, ну вот же код из ссылки:

     typedef const struct __CFDictionary * CFDictionaryRef;
     typedef struct __CFDictionary * CFMutableDictionaryRef;

по сути оба типа указатели на одну и ту же структуру (const -- это же просто бла-бла-бла для компилятора, к размеру памяти, выравниванию и проч. вещам, применимым к реальным машинным инструкциям отношения не имеет).

Comment: Кстати, а что не работает, если прямо написать приведение к CFDictionaryRef?

Т.е. если у Вас

     CFMutableDictionaryRef  x; 

и надо вызвать f(), которая требует аргумент типа CFDictionaryRef, то если просто написать

     f((CFDictionaryRef)x);

что именно не работает?